# webpack 4 to 5 migration support for closure compiler plugins

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, google-closure-compiler, webpack-5

I have a javascript/typescript code using webpack 4 for bundling in this code I am using `webpack-closure-compiler` plugin when I tried to upgrade to webpack 5 according to the [Docs](https://webpack.js.org/migrate/5/) I got the following error `[webpack-cli] TypeError: compiler.plugin is not a function` and it seems this plugin does not support webpack 5. google did not yield any results that work is there any other sulotion to use closure compiler in webpack 5?

Answer (score 0):

[webpack-closure-compiler](https://github.com/roman01la/webpack-closure-compiler) has been archived in 2019 and does not seem to be compatible with Webpack 5.

An alternative could be to use [closure-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/closure-webpack-plugin), but it doesn't seem compatible with Webpack 5 as it relies on Webpack 4 as a peer dependency.

As mentioned in [this Github issue](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/closure-webpack-plugin/issues/161), there hasn't been an update on Webpack 5 support since 2021.

But there's [google-closure-library-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/funte/google-closure-library-webpack-plugin) as a Webpack 5 alternative to both these plugins.

Comment: the google-closure-library-webpack-plugin has 9 - 40 downloads a week it does not seem to be very popular